# Testing NullOject in Grails Application

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, junit, null

Using grails 2.2.1 and having an issue with a service method which takes a NullObject as opposed to null.

The unit test is failing with the following exception;

```
|  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'class' on null object
at grails.test.GrailsMock$_createMock_closure1_closure2.doCall(GrailsMock.groovy:105)
at grails.test.GrailsMock$_createMock_closure1.doCall(GrailsMock.groovy:103)
```

The cacheService Unit test is as follows;

```
@Test
public void shouldCacheForCacheTypeJbossNullableObject() {

grailsApplication.config.domain.cache = "jbosscache"

cacheService.jbossCacheService = jbossMock.createMock()

cacheService.cacheWithNullable( at, ct, key, null ) 
jbossMock.verify()
}
```

The cacheService looks like this;

```
@Override
void cacheWithNullable(Token token, String type, String key, Object value)
{
    if(!value)
    {
       jbossCacheService.cache(token, type, key, new NullObject())
    }
}
```

Please note: some of the logic has been removed for clarity.

The jbossCacheService test case has 100% test coverage and operates as expected to ensure that nulls are not applied to cache. However, the cacheService test fails with NPE and I cant get this method test so that I can mock the return service or apply demands.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you directly calling NullObject?

Comment: Because the cache cant handle/operate with null but it can handle NullObject. The jbossCacheService class works as expected but its the cacheService which is calling the  jbossCacheService that is the issue in the JUnit. Testing against a bamboo release, the logic all works when deployed.

Comment: Some good reading on NullObject http://www.jworks.nl/2011/08/19/friday-repost-groovy-and-null/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the NullObject is a class-less class! So in the GrailsMock.class the following line of code is failing at line 105 will fail

```
   if (it != null) {
                    if (it.class instanceof Class) {
```

Which will mean the NullOject will pass the null check but fail on the instanceof. So the unit test will never pass with this logic. Might open an JIRA with Grails for a better explanation.